# How to parse a date in flutter to a json string compatible with Java ZonedDateTime

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, flutter, zoneddatetime

I have a Flutter app that needs to send a post request to my Spring Boot app. The object sent must have a Date in a json string format compatible with the ZonedDateTime java class. 
The pattern should be: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm[:ss[.S]]ZZ[{ZoneId}]`
An example of a date formatted correctly:

```
{
   'date':'2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'
}
```

I'm tried to use `time_machine 0.9.9` library at pub.dev, but it doesn't generate the correct pattern. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:time_machine/time_machine.dart';

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
    'date': '${Instant.now().inLocalZone()}'
}
```

Generates:

```
{
    "date":"2019-08-07T22:24:54 UTC (+00)"
}
```

Spring boot app throws an exception:

`` org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` from String "2019-08-07T22:24:54 UTC (+00)": Failed to deserialize java.time.ZonedDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019-08-07T22:24:54 UTC (+00)' could not be parsed at index 19 ``

Answer (score 2):

If you use just `Instant.now()` without `.inLocalZone()`, you will get like `2019-08-07T22:24:54Z`, which should be OK for your Spring Boot app.

`2019-08-07T22:24:54Z` is ISO 8601 format, which is the default format for modern Java date and time classes in the java.time API. So a Java `ZonedDateTime` parses it nicely. The error message said that `ZonedDateTime` was unable to parse the string that you got from `inLocalZone()`, quoted as `2019-08-07T22:24:54 UTC (+00)`.

This was posted as a guess in a comment at first, but another user confirmed that it worked for him/her, after which I posted this answer.

**Link.** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)